# error: wavread: No such file or directory in Octave

Tags: octave

I take the same error messages on different computers trying to use Octave in terminal:

```
wavread('example_audio.wav')
error: wavread: No such file or directory
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/audio/wavread.m at line 74, column 7
```

By the way, example_audio.wav is a working file (I tried in VLC player.) and I start Octave in the directory where .wav resides.
What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

EDIT: SOLVED. It seems the problem to be that I add the .wav file after I start Octave. After, exiting and starting again, it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the file name. Use tab to auto complete the filename to check if its found on your path.